# Lazy loading Lottie JSONs in web

Tags: javascript, lottie

Is there any way to lazy load lottie JSON files when using lottie-web (javascript)?
Right now my code is;

```
lottie.loadAnimation({
   container: document.querySelector('#lottie-1'),
   renderer: 'svg',
   loop: true,
   autoplay: true,
   path: 'https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_wzcckjq4.json'
});
```

Because this above code is showing up in Pagespeed Insights as enormous network payloads (totals to about 20MB in my case).
I tried placing it in DOMContentLoaded, readyState complete, window onload, and even setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

With 'scroll' event listener and simulating scroll event in window.onload worked for me.

```
<script>
var sc=0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(sc == 0){
        sc=1;
        lottie.loadAnimation({
            container: document.querySelector('#lottie-1'),
            renderer: 'svg',
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            path: 'https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_wzcckjq4.json'
        });
    }
});
window.onload = function() {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 1);
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 1);
};
</script>
```